# Should I quit a job I'm not happy with as a completely new graduate?

Tags: software-development, tech-industry, graduate

I need your advice as to how to proceed: I'm quite new in tech industry, 24, and just finished a year-long conversion course in CS.

2.5 months ago I started a new job in a big company that was advertised as Software Developer on LinkedIn, and in the interviews my manager assured me that it would be 50% programming, and 50% other project-related tasks. Needless to say, I was very excited to start.

Fast forward to present, and the job is nothing like I imagined. Admittedly, I'm doing stuff like data analysis, and other "tech-related" things, but there's no real programming and the team isn't a dev team, it's more support for SAAS products. Also, in the beginning my manager told me that the role was flexible and that I could let him know that I could choose what I wanted to focus on (software development, product management, etc.), but so far that hasn't been revisited.

I don't want to be dramatic or ungrateful, as I'm really happy that I managed to get a job straight out of university, but I want to grow as a developer and learn as much as possible, whereas my current role isn't focused on that at all.

I'm not sure what to do: I'm trying to stay positive and see it out, but I need advice on what's best for my career development: do I chill and wait it out and after a year try to move to a different department, do I speak to my manager (if so, when), or do I look for another job? I'm afraid the current one will pigeonhole me into a role that I don't want.

Any advice would be helpful as I really don't know what to do, thanks! Maybe someone has been in a similar position and could share their experience as well.

Comment: Have you talked to other people in the team about these issues? You won't imagine the number of problems that can easily be solved by just asking!

Comment: I'm not sure how to broach the topic as I'm new, and I don't want to seem ungrateful or that I'm complaining, not sure what to say to avoid that!

Comment: Well, if you have the intention to leave in case then what do you really have to lose? Speak in a calm and polite manner and ask your manager or someone with more experience in your team if there are any software-related tasks coming soon for you

Comment: No, I don't know if I should leave - I don't know what to do at all, what the better move would be in the long run, as it's a good company overall. But I definitely see your point about talking to someone, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Step 1:** look at what other people on your team are doing and talk to them how they feel. Whatever the seniors/principles are working on could be the stuff you would be working on in a few years if you stay. Determine whether you like this or not.
2. **Step2:** Research other departments in the company. Determine whether they do things that are more in line with your goals. Research culture and policies around internal transfers (which can vary greatly between companies).

Once you know the lay of the land, you can formulate a strategy. If there is cool work happening in the team, you can ask your manager to be part of it. "Hey boss, I think it's really cool what Alice is doing on the ABC project. Can I do something like this or work with her for a bit so I can learn how do do this?"

If nothing on the team looks good, but other teams do, then you can carefully stretch out some feelers on who may be interested in taking you in (provided the company is generally good with that). If you see a potentially viable path, talk to your manager about this as early as possible. It's best to do this openly.

If none of those seem promising, you can still consider to leave. Given that this is your first job, there is still a lot to learn (even if it's non-technical), so I wouldn't jump too quickly. One year would be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

**I would recommend that you keep this job while looking for another job that allows you to spend much more time writing code as you wish.** This new job could be an internal job within your current company or jobs outside your company.

Getting a job that fits your long term career goal is important as you are young and have a long career ahead.

> Should I quit a job I am not happy with as a new grad ?

**IMPORTANT NOTE: please do not quit this current job until you get an official job offer from a new company.**

If you quit your job now, you don't know when you will get a new job.

Furthermore, not always but some times, some employers may think that job applicants who are currently employed are kind of more "valuable" as the applicants are still working and getting more experiences daily...